# Azure App Service binding wildcard subdomain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am having troubles binding wildcard subdomains to azure web app.

I made necessary `DNS` records for mydomain.net:

`CNAME` * =>  myapp.azurewebsites.net

`TXT` asuid => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Now, I can bind specific subdomain in app bindings, such as: specificsubdomain.mydomain.net.

If I try to bind *.mydomain.net, it will end up with error :

```
Failed to assign custom domain *.mydomain.net on myapp. The domain name 'asuid.*.mydomain.net' is
 invalid. The provided record set relative name 'asuid.*' is invalid.
```

It seems to me as Azure Portal bug, as it is looking for **asuid.*** instead of **asuid**. (asuid.* is not valid `TXT` record and cannot be addded).

Is it correct? Is there any way to let Microsoft know this bug without paying for the support (paid bug reporting is in my mind bad in principle)?

Has anyone experienced this problem with any solution?

P.S.: wildcard binding is not a problem for deeper level, e.g. ***.useless.mydomain** using **asuid.useless** TXT record.

But that as a workaround is not acceptable - besides breaking the hierarchy it also needs yet another certificate covering *.useless.mydomain.net.

Answer (score 0):

When **Adding custom domain**, you should type a **fully qualified** domain name that matches the wildcard domain (for example, `sub1.contoso.com`), and then select Validate, rather than just `*.mydomain.net`.

And you could add multiple **fully qualified** domain name in the **Custom domain** page.
Like the pic in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#enable-the-cname-record-mapping-in-the-app):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this document. What if I want my app to handle all subdomains in a dynamic fassion? eg. userx.mydomain.net?

Comment: It might be a bug. I could reproduce the error in the classic portal, and I test with the **preview** portal, it could be set with `*.mydomain.net` successfully. You could raise a issue to Azure.